# Explain the 3 different flavors of string eval in perl

Tags: perl

I don't understand the explanations in the Perl documentation for the 3 different string eval types.  It doesn't help that the docs are garbled, with text missing, so that the beginning of a sentence doesn't fit with its end.

The three flavors are

- [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)
- [`evalbytes`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/evalbytes.html)<sup>[1]</sup>
- [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) with [`use feature qw( unicode_eval );`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#The-%27unicode_eval%27-and-%27evalbytes%27-features)

---

1. Requires `use feature qw( eval_bytes );` to use, or `CORE::evalbytes`.

Comment: I believe OP is referring to [this documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/feature#The-unicode_eval-and-evalbytes-features).

Comment: You might get better / more answers and less downvotes if you showed more effort on your own, i.e., tell us what particularly you don't understand.

Comment: It's actually straightforward question. "There's only a small difference between them; what is it?"

Comment: I think I know the difference, but I gotta run. I'll answer late tonight or tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

`use feature qw( unicode_eval )` is there to fix confusing quirks with vanilla `eval` that cannot be fixed without breaking backwards compatibility.

> eval behaves differently depending on the internal encoding of the string, sometimes treating its argument as a string of bytes, and sometimes as a string of characters.
>
> Source filters activated within eval leak out into whichever file scope is currently being compiled.

With `use feature qw( unicode_eval )` this changes. Now `eval` will always treat its code as characters (ie. UTF-8) and will not leak. This is most likely the behavior you want.

For those who *really, really* want code that's interpreted as bytes (ie. ASCII) there is `evalbytes`, but you probably don't need that.

***tl;dr***: If you're using 5.16 or newer and you're using `eval` (which you probably shouldn't), `use feature qw( unicode_eval )` and `eval`. It supports UTF-8 and it fixes `eval` quirks.

Or just [`use utf8::all`](https://metacpan.org/pod/utf8::all) and forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing a bunch of experiments to get the answer to this question.  I had already ruled out Schwern's answer before I posted the question.  The documentation that was somewhat garbled was in perlfunc.  (That and the documentation in feature.pm largely overlapped.)  The result is that I've changed the documentation to reflect what I found.  This is now in perl 5.25.10, and should be in 5.26.  I changed the feature.pm documentation to be just a short summary with no detail, linking to perlfunc for the meat of the behavior.   Here is a link to the difference listing of the commit that changed this.  I believe that it adequately describes the way things actually work.  But patches are welcome.

[commit diff](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commitdiff/9891e9b7d5c8747ecfb7ce7038187b087bd8c655)

The text is weak on the flaws that existed before the features were added.  I examined all the emails I could find on the subject from the perl5-porters email list, but didn't find anything beyond what I wrote in the patch